# Необязательно или Не обязательно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Администрация уведомит работников о том, что они утратили право
> уплачивать за льготный кредит, но дожидаться такого оповещения не
> обязательно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Администрация уведомит работников о том, что они утратили право уплачивать за льготный кредит, но дожидаться такого оповещения **необязательно**.*

НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО, нареч. 1. к Необязательный (3 зн.). Смежники вели себя крайне н. 2. **в функц. сказ. О том, что не является обязательным, непременным; нет необходимости**. Вам н. приезжать самому. Ему н. лечиться в санатории. Н., чтобы об этом все знали.

Смысл такой: нет необходимости дожидаться оповещения (можно запросить инормацию раньше).

Раздельное написание в приципе возможно, но оно связано с **логическим подчеркиванием,** а для этого в данном сообщении делового стиля **нет особых причин.**